# calculating differences in species distribution over time

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap

I have been searching a lot but I didn't find any useful solution yet.
I have a shapefile representing range polygons for different species of primates and rasters representing current and future environmental conditions or predictors. What I would like to do is to assess for each species if there is any difference when subtracting  future - present rasters of each predictor within species range. I have been trying to do this in ArcGIS 10.5 by extracting all predictors using primate shapefile as a mask, using raster calculation and reclassify tools, but it came up with results for primates and not for each primate species.

Any suggestion about how to do this in ArcGIS?

I am a bit familiar with R (more than ArcGIS), so if any script/package is available to do this in R I don't mind to give it a try too.

Comment: How many species is it? You could create a new layer for each species polygon and then create modelbuilder tool to do the extractions faster and get results for each species individually.

Comment: Since this is volumetric problem, this should really be done in a probabilistic manner. Hurlbert has a 1978 Ecology paper "The Measurement of Niche Overlap and Some Relatives" that nicely covers the math behind integration of niche volumes. This will be a good starting point for you to expand your question so that you will receive a relevant answer. Changes in binary species range is quite a pointless exercise.

Comment: Please decide which of R and ArcGIS Desktop you wish to ask about in this particular question and remove reference to the other. That way you and potential answerers can focus on precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck using that.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I have approximately 400 species and I could split the original layer to each species. I also had a look at the modelbuilder tool (thanks for this great suggestion!), but I am not having success in the first step to include each species. I am thinking to build a model with 1) split by attribute (e.g. field representing species name), 2) extract or clip (including layers representing e.g. present and future climate, present and future human population...), 3) raster calculator (future - present), and 4) summary statistics. Any idea about how to improve this to each species?